# <type>[,] <name> notation in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

I am a python guy, and have recently started learning C#, mostly through we tutorials and code snippets I find. I came across a function (inside a public class) with this signature:

```
private void compute(double[,] data)
```

I understand everything there, except for `double[,] data`.
It seems similar to the `double[] data` notation, which would mean "an array of `double`s". However, the `[,]` is throwing me off.

Could someone please explain to me what that syntax expresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means a **2D non-jagged array.** Of `double`s in this case.

Basically, a storage system that you can fetch with two coordinates. Like a map. Mentally, you could say it's something like this:

```
4 5 6 4
2 3 4 3
2 4 7 2
2 3 4 2
```

This syntax is expansible, so for example `double[,,]` would mean a 3D array, `double[,,,]` would mean a 4D array, etc.

To create them, you use this syntax:

```
double[,] myArr = new double[4,23];
```

To fetch an item from them, you use this syntax:

```
myArr[3,6];
```

Comment: I understand that I could use `n-1` `,`s to indicate an n-dimensional non-jagged array. But for large `n`, that's a lot of commas. Is there an associated shorthand, perhaps `double[,10]` for 10D?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget No, there isn't. It'd be quite useless as you'd still have you type out something like `myArray[4,2,3,5,76,2,43]` etc. when fetching a value.

Comment: No-one uses `double[,,,,,,,,,]` after all, so who cares about a shorthand?

Answer (score 2):

its a 2 dimensional array of doubles .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.71).aspx

so you can do...

```
double[,] myArray = new double[4,2];
```

and

`myArray[1,1] = 0.3;`

Comment: Oh! Would I be able to abuse the syntax then to do `double [,,]` for a 3D array of doubles?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: It's not "abuse" at all - that's simply the syntax for a 3D array...

Comment: zOMG! @JonSkeet just answered my question. (Sorry about the fangirl-ing, but this is what normal people must feel like when Summer Glau high-fives them)

Comment: given @JonSkeet rep, he's more likely than anyone else on here to answer a question ;)

Comment: @KeithNicholas: I've been on here for 3 years. This is the first time he's answered my post. I think the subject matter of my post plays a large role (like I said, I'm a python guy)